# IIS Settings application pool idle timeout causes WPF not responding

Tags: asp.net, wpf, web-services, iis, freeze

I  have a Window Presentation Framework application that uses web services to load data in user interface. I notice that when i leave my application idle for 10 min and access my application again, my application is not responding for 3-10 sec. After some research i choose to set my application pool idle timeout in Internet Information  Services to 0 and my problem solved. I have some understanding that after i leave my application idle for 10 min, my OS will free up the memory resource that allocate to my web services processes but i still have some doubt on this.

My question is
1) The default idle timeout is set to 20 min, why the OS terminate my process after i left my application idle for 10 minute only?

2) During the first time when i log in to my system, why there is no "not responding" issues given that the application just started to call the web service? I assume the application will need to call the web service again after i idle for 10 min and the OS terminate my process but this time my application become not responding..